# Sorting is canceled after change datasource

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I have silverlight application that each 1 second changes the observable collection but what happend is that after you sort the sort is canceled.
how can i solve it?
this happens each 1 second:

```
private async void ClockTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var allOpenTrades = await NewAPI.GetOpenTrades();
    var openLongTrades = allOpenTrades.Where(x => x.gameType == (int)GameType.LongTerm);
    LongTermModel.Open = new ObservableCollection<OpenTranasctionLongTerm>
    (openLongTrades.Select(x => new OpenTranasctionLongTerm
    {                   
        isPut = x.CallPutStatusId == 2,
        DateTraded = x.TransactionCreatedOn.ToLocalTime(),
        Expiration = x.optionExpirationTime.ToLocalTime(),
        Payout = x.OptionWinReturn,
        Security = x.OptionName,
        StrikePrice = x.TransactionQuote,
        Traded = x.Amount,
        Currency = UserCurrency,
        isCall = x.CallPutStatusId == 1,
        Type = x.CallPutStatusId == 1 ? "Call" : "Put"
    }).ToList());
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "after you sort the sort is cancled"? can you elaborate your question little bit more?

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/3osxYvir0B3KjzRz9u/giphy.gif  this is what happend i refresh its all cool then it updates its data and the sort is cancled @RafiqueMohammed

Comment: @scichart Can you specify the type of ItemsControl you use(DataGrid or ListView)? Have you a third party control as a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you reset(create a new observable collection) your collection each timer tick, thus in my opinion, the [sort description](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDataGridSorting.aspx) of a DataGrid's ItemsSource is cleared. I think that if will replace your re-creating(creating the new observable collection) code with the next one, it will help you to preserve the origin sort description.

**A new ClockTimerOnTick method code**

```
    private void ClockTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var allOpenTrades = NewAPI.GetOpenTrades();
        var openLongTrades = allOpenTrades.Where(x => x.gameType == (int)GameType.LongTerm).ToList();
        //I'm assuming here that the LongTermModel.Open is an observable collection
        LongTermModel.Open.Clear();
        openLongTrades.ForEach(term =>
        {
            LongTermModel.Open.Add(new OpenTranasctionLongTerm
            {
                isPut = x.CallPutStatusId == 2,
                DateTraded = x.TransactionCreatedOn.ToLocalTime(),
                Expiration = x.optionExpirationTime.ToLocalTime(),
                Payout = x.OptionWinReturn,
                Security = x.OptionName,
                StrikePrice = x.TransactionQuote,
                Traded = x.Amount,
                Currency = UserCurrency,
                isCall = x.CallPutStatusId == 1,
                Type = x.CallPutStatusId == 1 ? "Call" : "Put"
            });
        });
    }
```

Here we just clear and re-fill the LongTermModel.Open collection each timer tick.

Regards.